I try to visualize groups of data with a line plot but each group has changing data on the x-axis
I am trying to solve a business problem. I was asked to do a line plot. Basically I have packages, which all contains x number of cases. Each package has a purchase date, which ranges from 1990 to 2024. In the cases of the packages there can be an agreement or not, and if there is an agreement in a case, the agreement has a date on which it was done. Let's say I have 10 packages with each 1000 cases in those, and I want to visualize how many agreement was done in each package. The X-axis should contain the number of months passed since the purchasing of the package (this is the problem, because it varies for every package) and the Y-axis should contain the number of agreements in a package.
Example: If i have a package Z which was bought in 2024 January then it's 6 months since it was bought, then it had 10 agreements done within that package until February, 50 until march, 120 till may and so on (this is calculated based on when the agreement was done).
I want all packages to start from the origo point, which makes this task harder.
Then I want to filter for some columns within the packages, but these filters are on the cases level. For example i want to filter for the business branch which might be different for the cases within the package. The leadership needs this to visualize how the progress is going in the different packages over the months.
I would like to know if it is feasible at all, or what kind of methods would be recommended.
I tried using dataframes and visualization libraries, but I can only achieve half of this. If I make the x axis work on this manner, then I have to aggregate to package level, which will not allow me to filter on the case level, and vice versa.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
